# Packaging app With Electron and Asar

Tags: javascript, webview, electron, asar, adapt

I have this weird problem, I'm trying to make the website work offline (elearning course made with Adapt), so I've created the Electron App wrapper:

`main.js` creates the `BrowserWindow` which then loads `index.html`

```
function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        "min-width": 800,
        "min-height": 530,
        resize: true,
        "use-content-size": true
    });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

    // Open the DevTools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    // Set Window Resizable
    mainWindow.isResizable(true);

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}
```

the launcher of the course (that hosts the webview tag)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #6e6e6e;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        webview {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <webview src="build/scorm_test_harness.html" disablewebsecurity></webview>
</body>

</html>
```

and the problem starts when I've turned off the developer tools panel, once done the course is no longer loaded, when I uncomment `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();` then it works again, at the moment I'm using this workaround:

```
// Open the DevTools.
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
// Close (almost) immediately
setTimeout(function (webContents) {
    webContents.closeDevTools();
}, 100, mainWindow.webContents);
```

and it works but it is an ugly patch, any thoughts on that anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Add non-empty `<script>` tag somewhere in `head`.

---

**Explanation:**

If there is no scripts on page, `Chrome` thinks page has no dynamic content on it and doesn't creates scripting context, which prohibits from `electron` core scripts to be injected into page, and that scripts responsible about `webview` tag handling (*there is issue reports about this bug on electron github repo, but developers of electron stated, that that is intended behaviour (in Chrome core), apparently, `not a bug, but a feature`* xD).

---

Here's related issue [link](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1117).

Comment: can you elaborate, what where and why?

Comment: was in process of adding explanation =)